# Dataset wont load with iOS-Charts

Tags: ios, objective-c, charts, ios-charts

I have a view controller that's just a full screen ios-chart view nested in a nav controller. This was working in October and I've looked through my git repo and nothing has changed about this file. However I did pull in the latest version from the repo and I achieved the same results.

So first I have a setup function that sets up chart:

```
if (vertical)
{
    self.barChart = [[BarChartView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
}
else
{
    self.barChart = [[HorizontalBarChartView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
}
self.barChart.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.barChart.delegate = self;

self.barChart.descriptionText = @"";
self.barChart.noDataTextDescription = @"";

self.barChart.drawBarShadowEnabled = NO;
self.barChart.drawValueAboveBarEnabled = YES;
self.barChart.rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = NO;
self.barChart.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = NO;
self.barChart.maxVisibleValueCount = 60;
self.barChart.pinchZoomEnabled = NO;
self.barChart.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = NO;
self.barChart.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
ChartXAxis *xAxis = self.barChart.xAxis;
xAxis.labelPosition = XAxisLabelPositionBottom;
xAxis.labelFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.f];
xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = NO;
xAxis.spaceBetweenLabels = 0;

ChartYAxis *leftAxis = self.barChart.leftAxis;
leftAxis.labelFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.f];
leftAxis.labelCount = 3;
leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = YES;
leftAxis.valueFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
leftAxis.valueFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0;
leftAxis.valueFormatter.positivePrefix = @"$";
leftAxis.valueFormatter.negativePrefix = @"-$";
leftAxis.labelPosition = YAxisLabelPositionOutsideChart;
leftAxis.spaceTop = 0.25;

[self.barChart.legend setEnabled:false];
[self refresh]; //refreshes data for charting
```

Refresh on self grabs the JSON off my website and forms it into an array of dictionaries and then calls this:

```
NSMutableArray *xAxis = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *yAxis = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int x = 0; x < data.count; x++) {
    [xAxis addObject:data[x][@"title"]];
    [yAxis addObject:[[BarChartDataEntry alloc] initWithValue:floor([data[x][@"value"] doubleValue]) xIndex:x]];
}
BarChartDataSet *set1 = [[BarChartDataSet alloc] initWithYVals:yAxis label:self.barTitle];
set1.barSpace = 0.35;
set1.colors = @[[[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.007843137255 green:0.2117647059 blue:0.4470588235 alpha:1]];
set1.valueFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
set1.valueFormatter.positivePrefix = @"$";
set1.valueFormatter.negativePrefix = @"-$";
[set1.valueFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
set1.valueFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0;
NSMutableArray *dataSets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[dataSets addObject:set1];

BarChartData *barData = [[BarChartData alloc] initWithXVals:xAxis dataSets:dataSets];
[barData setValueFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:10.f]];

self.barChart.data = barData;
```

The dataset is correct and gets all 24 values and appears to setup the xAxis and yAxis correctly but after all this, my chart just displays "No chart data available"
I've searched around and didn't find many articles on this but one suggestion was use dispatch_after to run setNeedsDisplay on the bar chart:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.barChart setNeedsDisplay];
});
```

I've tried that code with 30 seconds as my timer to be absolutely sure the chart library finished doing what it needs to with that data and still the chart shows no data.

Any and all help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you sure self.barChart.data = barData; is the same chart view? Your code seems fine, and should never display no data text. I am thinking your self.barChart is different object.

Comment: Yes. I even deleted and recreated the link between my class and the storyboard. It's the correct instance.

Comment: I think you must be making a obvious somewhere else than your posted code. I suggest you starting debugging the chart renderer's code to see if get drawn by starting adding break points at drawRect.

Comment: I breakpointed drawRect and the instance var _data is still nil after setting it in my class. Then I looked at the line where data is set and immediately after stepping over that line in the debugger, data is still nil in the barChart.

Comment: How can that even be possible?

Comment: something must twist your object, you can now break the data setter